# pandoc-ruby errors

Tags: ruby, pandoc

I have just installed pandoc using gem install pandoc-ruby and have tried running this sample script:

```
require 'pandoc-ruby'
@converter = PandocRuby.new('# Markdown Title', :from => :markdown, :to => :rst)
puts @converter.convert
```

I get the following errors:

```
open3.rb:202: in spawn': No such file or directory - pandoc --from=markdown --to=rst (Errno::ENOENT)
open3.rb:202: inpopen_run'
open3.rb:90: in popen3'
pandoc-ruby.rb:101: inexecute'
pandoc-ruby.rb:77: in convert'
pandoc test.rb:3: in'
```

I assume that as the script is one of the ones given as an example on the pandoc-ruby github that there must be something wrong with the installation. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error looks like Ruby is unable to find the pandoc executable.

To tell Pandoc where to find the executable, use the `bin_path` method:

```
PandocRuby.bin_path='/usr/local/bin'
```

Set `bin_path` to the directory where you put the pandoc executable.

Comment: Would you be so kind to tell me where to add this configuration option?

Comment: @EugenevanderMerwe Did you figure it out, where to put this option?